# Change date format in Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular14

I am working on angular application and I have an array as follows:

data:

```
[
 {
   "id:"1",
   "date":"2021-06-28T00:00:00.00Z",
   "name":"A"
 },
  {
   "id:"2",
   "date":"2022-06-28T00:00:00.00Z",
   "name":"A"
 },
  {
   "id:"3",
   "date":"2023-06-28T00:00:00.00Z",
   "name":"A"
 }
]
```

Like this I may have 100-200 records in array.
In my html I have code as follows:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data">
{{data.date}}
</div>
```

I want to disaply date in following format: "June22", "Nov23" etc. How can I convert date to required format at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

With the built-in `date` pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let data of data">
{{data.date | date: 'MMMYY'}}
</div>
```

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Comment: it is giving output in numbers. for June it is givng 06. I want June, Oct , Nov etc

Comment: Read the doc provided in the answer, `MMM` will give you Jun, Oct, Nov; and `MMMM` will show full month names

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an Angular seasoned developer but I have achieved what you are asking using 'Pipes'.
Here is the link to [Transforming Data Using Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#transforming-data-using-pipes). Specifically, you may find it handy to use a [DatePipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe).

For instance: (taken from the link above)

```
<p>The hero's birthday is {{ birthday | date:"MM/dd/yy" }} </p>
```

I think you may be looking for something like:

```
'mediumDate'    'MMM d, y'  Jun 15, 2015
```

Take a look at the first link I have provided. I hope this may help you.